# What is the total number of candidates taking the exam?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$40 \%$ of candidates passed the examination. $60$ people are in the $5\%$ reserve list. What is the total number of candidates taking the exam?

$$= \frac{40}{100} \times 100 $$

$$= 40$$

$$= 40 + 60$$

$$= 100$$

The correct answer is $1200$. How to calculate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is about taking the exam and not passing it.
5% of taking = 60 so 
10% = 120
 and then 100% = 1200

but your question isn't very clear and it is maybe a mistake, because the definition of the "5% reserve list" is ambiguous